# In Rails 3 with haml-rails, why would =text_field :project... set params and not %input{:name => "project"...}?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, haml

If I do the following line in haml

`%input#project_images{:name => "project[project_images]", :type=>'text', :value => @project_images.join(',') }/`

My `projects_controller` is returns `params[:project][:project_images]` as an empty string `""`

On the other hand if I use the rails shortcut:

`= text_field( :project, :project_images, :value => @project_images.join(','))`

It works, and returns a string `"1,2,3"`

Here are the outputted html from the two different lines

```
<input id="project_images" name="project[project_images]" type="text" value="1,2,3">
<input id="project_project_images" name="project[project_images]" size="30" type="text" value="1,2,3">
```

Comment: What if you change `%input#project_images` to `%input#project_project_images` ?